# Braintree with Magento 2 - Configuration

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, paypal, braintree

We are facing an issue with Braintree Module in Magento 2 with Sandbox.

PayPal:

[image]

Credit Card:

[image]

We have set up an account as per Magento guideline (https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/braintree.html)

but still not working.

I have check payment.log but not able to get any response data.

```
[2018-09-07 11:06:56] main.DEBUG: array (
  'request' => 
  array (
    'customer' => 
    array (
      'firstName' => 'kaushal',
      'lastName' => 'chauhan',
      'company' => 'CP',
      'phone' => '111-222-3333',
      'email' => 'kaushal@yahoo.com',
    ),
    'amount' => '3.00',
    'paymentMethodNonce' => 'tokencc_bc_bxqv9x_y5vscx_bqyy9s_kvybcn_9z5',
    'orderId' => '000000050',
    'merchantAccountId' => 'xmfnjz54mtzfjp6w',
    'channel' => 'Magento2_Cart_Community_BT',
    'billing' => 
    array (
      'firstName' => 'kaushal',
      'lastName' => 'chauhan',
      'company' => 'CP',
      'streetAddress' => 'address',
      'extendedAddress' => '',
      'locality' => 'greer',
      'region' => 'SC',
      'postalCode' => '29650',
      'countryCodeAlpha2' => 'US',
    ),
    'shipping' => 
    array (
      'firstName' => 'kaushal',
      'lastName' => 'chauhan',
      'company' => 'CP',
      'streetAddress' => 'address',
      'extendedAddress' => '',
      'locality' => 'greer',
      'region' => 'SC',
      'postalCode' => '29650',
      'countryCodeAlpha2' => 'US',
    ),
    'options' => 
    array (
      'storeInVaultOnSuccess' => true,
    ),
    'store_id' => 1,
  ),
  'client' => 'Magento\\Braintree\\Gateway\\Http\\Client\\TransactionSale',
  'response' => 
  array (
  ),
) [] []
```

also, need to confirm anyone has used with Magento REST API with braintree??

Comment: I would suggest not displaying full credit card numbers (see your second screenshot).

Comment: drs6222, its dummy sandbox credit card and it will not work on production mode..:)

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Based off of the response object you included it appears that you are passing your merchant ID in for the merchant account ID field. I would recommend checking the value you entered in your Magento admin panel with your sandbox's [merchant account ID](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/important-gateway-credentials#merchant-account-id).

You mentioned above that the credit card number used is a test card number, but Braintree's sandbox will only accept our own [test card numbers](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing#credit-card-numbers). After you correct the merchant account ID value I would try another test using one of our test card numbers as well as try out another test PayPal transaction attempt. 
 
Please reach out to Braintree Support if you have any other questions.